# Is there a way to increase the chance of a rare Pokemon at a certain location?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm particularly interested in increasing the chance of them appearing in my house, and specifically my basement.

Incidentally, does the altitude of the location matter at all?

Answer (score 1):

The only two ways to increase pokemon spawn rate is through incense which attracts them to you and through lure modules which attracts them to a specific pokestop. Since I doubt you have a pokestop in your basement your only option would be to use incense. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This game relies of GPS coord. Logitude and Latitude. The altitude you are at in your basement vs your living room given a fixed GPS coord does not change what Pokemon appears or how often they appear.